# pdfinfo manpage is incomplete

Tags: pdf, metadata

I use pdfinfo and do not find in the [manpage](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pdfinfo1.html) what `Suspects`, `Form` and `UserProperties` mean. In my case I get with `pdfinfo foo.pdf`:

```
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
```

What do this entries mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stumbled upon this as well.  A quick glance at the [source code](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/tree/utils/pdfinfo.cc?id=6d3239a2fd04595fecfb81a8703794877f4d8dec#n319) gives the following chunk related to these properties:

```
// print tagging info
printf("Tagged:         %s\n",
  (doc->getCatalog()->getMarkInfo() & Catalog::markInfoMarked) ? "yes" : "no");
printf("UserProperties: %s\n",
  (doc->getCatalog()->getMarkInfo() & Catalog::markInfoUserProperties) ? "yes" : "no");
printf("Suspects:       %s\n",
  (doc->getCatalog()->getMarkInfo() & Catalog::markInfoSuspects) ? "yes" : "no");

// print form info
switch (doc->getCatalog()->getFormType())
{
case Catalog::NoForm:
  printf("Form:           none\n");
  break;
case Catalog::AcroForm:
  printf("Form:           AcroForm\n");
  break;
case Catalog::XfaForm:
  printf("Form:           XFA\n");
  break;
}
```

The first three properties are related to Tagged PDFs.  I am not certain what all is entailed with a Tagged PDF, but the [PDF reference](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) provides some information starting in section 10.6.

The `Form` property appears to return what types of form exist in the PDF (or could exist?).  For my PDF in question, I obtain `AcroForm` although the document does not appear to actually contain a form.  A quick description of the difference between the form options is [provided here](https://appligent.com/what-is-the-difference-between-acroforms-and-xfa/).